# why my updateOrInsert doesn't work laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use updateOrInsert to avoid duplicate data, why doesn't the Update function work and always insert data?

```
foreach($datas as $data){
                    DB::table('users')->updateOrInsert([
                        'user_connect_id' => $user->connect_id,
                        'description' => $data['description'],
                        'created_by' => $login->name,
                        'modified_by' => $login->name,
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    ]);
                }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [updateOrInsert] this documentation (https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert). You need two parameters. One is the matching attributes (i.e., the attributes you would use to identify your record in case it exists), the other is your array (the new values you wish to insert or update the record with).

```
updateOrInsert(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

**Example**

```
DB::table('users')->updateOrInsert(
    [
        'user_connect_id' => $user->connect_id
    ],
    [
        'user_connect_id' => $user->connect_id,
        'description' => $data['description'],
        'created_by' => $login->name,
        'modified_by' => $login->name,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two arguments in updateOrInsert method.The updateOrInsert method accepts two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the record, and an array of column and value pairs containing the columns to be updated.

For e.g :

```
DB::table('users')
    ->updateOrInsert(
        ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
        ['votes' => '2']
    );
```

Check this link for syntax : [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Inseart code
 public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.category.create');
    }
     public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required'
            ]);
            $category = new Category();
            $category->name = $request->name;
            $category->slug = str_slug($request->name);
            $category->save();
            Toastr::success('Category Successfully Saved','Success');
            return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
        }
    // Update code
        public function edit($id)
        {
            $category =Category::find($id);
            return view('admin.category.edit',compact('category'));
        }

       public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required|unique:categories'
            ]);
            $category = Category::find($id);
            $category->name = $request->name;
            $category->slug = str_slug($request->name);
            $category->save();
            Toastr::success('Category Successfully Updated','Success');
            return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean?